# drush drupal openshift update core

Tags: drupal-7, openshift, drush

i am trying to update the core of drupal with drush on openshift by entering "drush up drupal" but im getting this error message

> Directory /var/lib/openshift/[userid] exists, but is not writable.
>   Please check directory permissions.Unable to create backup directory
>   /var/lib/openshift/[userid]//drush-backups/drupal1.

ive tried

> chmod +w /var/lib/openshift/[userid]

to make the directory writeable but i dont have the necessary permissions.

What is the best way to update drupal core on openshift if drush doesnt work?

Thanks for any info on that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

> drush up drupal --no-backup

Comment: perfect! a zillion thanks! did a "rhc save-snapshot <appname>" before so no need for the drushbackup.